# Recreate activity with different extras

Tags: java, android

I need to recreate Activity - open a new screen with different extras,
when I try to do that with `recreate()` it works perfectly,
but there is an ugly black screen.

```
 setIntent(intent);
 this.recreate();
```

When I try to `finish()` and `startActivity(newIntent)` there is no black screen but in some way `onCreate()` called before `onDestroy()`

```
 finish();
 startActivity(newIntent);
```

this is my newIntent:

```
 Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, DeviceActivity.class);
 newIntent.putExtra(Consts.INTENT_ID, device.getID());
 newIntent.putExtra(Consts.INTENT_DEVICE_NAME, device.getID());
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "recreate"? What do you want the user to see? Is it a new screen with different data? Or do you want to change the data on the current screen? In other words, do you want each screen saved on the back stack so that the user can go back to any screen with its data?

Comment: what I need is new screen with different data, this screen is 1 instance so no need to save to back stack.
I just wand to finish current activity and recreate with new data

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter how often `onCreate()` is being called; just check for `savedInstanceState == null`, in order to determine when to run code within that method. When it runs for the first time, `savedInstanceState` will always be `null`. Moving some heavy code outside of method `onCreate()` might also make sense, in case it could run later on in the `Activity` life-cycle.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not related, i always get `savedInstanceState = null`.
but in some reason `onCreate()` called twice after activity recreation

Comment: This is certainly relevant. The question is rather why you destroy it in-between? Because when destroying it, the next instance will not be restarted, but regularity started - and `savedInstanceState` is then `null` again. You've probably provided too little code to tell what is going on there (because this behavior is not "normal").

Answer (score 0):

One solution here is to call `startActivity()` without calling `finish()`. This will create a new instance of your activity, basically a new screen but using the same code.

But this depends entirely on what you want the user to see. We should talk about this in terms of the user interaction, not in terms of "activities" and "intents" which are implementation details.

Comment: What you have suggested here works logically, but in terms of UI I would like to close the activity and open a new one with the new data

Comment: @Arik6 I suggest that you just display the new data in the current activity then. You should look at fragments. They can help abstract this kind of thing into a reusable piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was that I had connecting/disconnecting to some manager that fired from `onCreate() & onDestroyed()`.

onDestroyed() Happens asynchronously and we have no way of knowing when the system will reach it (Even we call `finish()`).

so after I moved this manager launching to `onPause() & onResume()` it works smoothly and it solve my problem.

thank you all for your help